# Find out which phone numbers are local in ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, telephony, nslocale

I'd like to show the user a list of their contacts (using `ABAddressBook`) that are only in the user's current locale so the user **doesn't incur any international texting fees**. For example, if the user has a phone in the USA only USA phone numbers should show up.

My option right now is to get the user's current locale (comes up as a 2 character string I believe) and compare that to the country code of any phone numbers with a 00 or + at the beginning. Any phone number without a 00 or + is guaranteed to be local, but if someone has a phone number with +1 it should still be considered local...but that could also be a Canadian number. How can I differentiate between those?

Any other ideas?